# How to query Json array in jsonb in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column which have following rows

ROW1:

```
 [
        {
            "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:sgi:irix:3.55:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:university_of_washington:imap:10.234:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
            "active": true
        }
    ]
```

ROW 2:

```
 []
```

ROW 3:

```
[
    {
        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:o:sgi:irix:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
        "active": true
    }
]
```

I want to find the rows which contain *sgi:irix* in the key *cpe23Uri*

Which query should i use for best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `exists` condition with a correlated subquery that uses `jsonb_array_element()` to unnest and search the array:

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.js) x
    where  x->>'cpe23Uri' like '%sgi:irix%'
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8d5f6b25f14cee203b4eca57b00df86)**

Comment: It works great! Is there any way to make it faster? because it need about 3 seconds to get the results. I have to run this query for a big analyse 15M times which can take 1 month so.. any idea?

Comment: select *  from t
WHERE t.products @>'[{"cpe23Uri":"cpe:2.3:a:sgi:irix:0.1.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"}]'::jsonb;       This query takes only 1 second but without LIKE operator..